# Autofac & MassTransit - Register Consumer ObjectDisposedException

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac, masstransit

Context: ASP.NET Core App (1.1).

I try to resolve the IRepository that i've already registered when i need a consumer instance, but it looks like i receive a ObjectDisposedException.

[image: BusFactoryMethod]

I created a bus factory method that auto activates when i call `.Build()` method of the `ContainerBuilder`.

```
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
  var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
  containerBuilder.RegisterType<EventTypeResolver>().As<IEventTypeResolver>();
  containerBuilder.RegisterType<Repository>().As<IRepository>();
  containerBuilder.Register(c => EventStoreConnectionFactory.Create())
                            .As<IEventStoreConnection>();
  containerBuilder.Register(BusFactoryMethod).AsSelf().SingleInstance().AutoActivate();
  containerBuilder.Populate(services);
  return new AutofacServiceProvider(containerBuilder.Build());
}
```

`BusFactoryMethod` looks like this:

```
 private IBusControl BusFactoryMethod(IComponentContext componentContext)
 {
    var busControl = BusConfigurator.Instance.ConfigureBus((cfg, host) =>
            {
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RabbitMQConstants.UserManagementQueue, e =>
                {
                    e.Consumer(() => new CreateUserCommandConsumer(componentContext.Resolve<IRepository>()));
                });
            });
    busControl.Start();
    return busControl;
 }
```

Comment: You are registering your `IRepository` as transient dependency, but your `IBusControl` is singfleton and depending on where from you resolve `IBusControl`, i..e if you resolve it somewhere during a request, its resolved by the scoped container, but since its singleton it goes to the parent container while the IRepository is resolved by the scoped container and disposed at the end of request, but `IBusControl` won't get disposed because its singleton

Comment: So you will have to either resolve `IBusControl` during application startup `Configure` method, or change both `IRepository` and `IBusControl` scoped lifetime (probably not possible as you want to listen to events and messages)

Comment: Hmmm. Yes, that's the case as i register that BusFactoryMethod with AutoActivate it will get called when i build the container. But the Consumer/Repository will be there just for request lifetime

Comment: Yes, but the factory method will still reference the previous scoped container instance `IComponentContext `, which has been disposed at the end of the request time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've found a package `MassTransit.AutofacIntegration` which already has a `RegisterConsumers` method.

Then i used Autofac's `RegisterGeneric` method in order to get a lifetime per message.

```
  containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(AutofacConsumerFactory<>))
                             .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("name", "message"))
                             .As(typeof(IConsumerFactory<>))
                             .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

And ended up with the following `Module`:

```
   public class DefaultModule : Autofac.Module
        {
            protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
            {
                containerBuilder.Register(c => new EventTypeResolver(typeof(DefaultModule).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)).As<IEventTypeResolver>();
                containerBuilder.Register(c => EventStoreConnectionFactory.Create())
                                .As<IEventStoreConnection>();
                containerBuilder.RegisterType<Repository>().As<IRepository>();
                containerBuilder.RegisterConsumers(typeof(DefaultModule).GetTypeInfo().Assembly).AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces();
                containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(AutofacConsumerFactory<>))
                             .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("name", "message"))
                             .As(typeof(IConsumerFactory<>))
                             .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                containerBuilder.Register((c) =>
                {
                    var busControl = BusConfigurator.Instance.ConfigureBus((cfg, host) =>
                    {
                        ConfigureEndPoints(cfg, host, c);
                    });
                    busControl.Start();
                    return busControl;
                }).SingleInstance().AutoActivate();
            }

            private void ConfigureEndPoints(IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator cfg, IRabbitMqHost host, IComponentContext context)
            {
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RabbitMQConstants.UserManagementQueue, e =>
                {
                    e.Consumer(context.Resolve<IConsumerFactory<CreateUserCommandConsumer>>());
                });
            }
        }
```

`ConfigureServices` method is now looking like this:

```
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
            containerBuilder.RegisterModule<DefaultModule>();
            containerBuilder.Populate(services);
            return new AutofacServiceProvider(containerBuilder.Build());
        }
```

Comment: You might be surprised but Autofac adapter is described in the documentation http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/containers/autofac.html